# Will partitioning a table prevent table locking?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

If I partition my table by customerId will this prevent the whole table from being locked if a customer decides to delete 20,000 records? We have some customers that perform a massive amount of deleted, inserts, and updates. I will like the locking to be restricted to the customer partition only so it does not affect other customer partitions. If I partition the data by the customerid will this prevent the whole from being locked?

Comment: Not on its own. Look up [`ALTER TABLE ... SET (LOCK_ESCALATION)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Doesn't that state that locks will not escalate to the table by default?

Comment: @DavidG: no -- it states that `LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO` will not do that, but also that the default is `TABLE`. (I haven't actually tested this myself, I've only used `DISABLE` on occasion. However, simply turning off lock escalation, tempting as it sounds, isn't always the right solution.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh, I assumed AUTO was default. I should have kept reading...

Comment: @DavidG: to be fair, the default *ought* to be `AUTO` in new databases since it's more sane, but this may be someone's penchant for backwards compatibility (SQL Server is rather big on that). Or the docs are wrong, hence my disclaimer on not having tested it. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't mind the backwards compat too much, it's probably fine for 99.5% of all users and the remaining 0.5% should know what they're doing enough to be able to change these things. Either that, or maybe an option on install to set up with all the turbo buttons turned on with a huge disclaimer :)